# Regex pattern match

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to add a regex filter to the script below (just before the array_push) so that, when it encounters files that have the same prefix "_filename" and one of the matches has '-150x150.' at the end of the filename, it pushes that image and skips the others with the same prefix.

However, if there are no images in that collection that have '-150x150.' in the filename, it selects the image with the root prefix (_filename.ext)

For example, if the following files reside in the $dir folder:

```
_file.png
_file-150x150.png
_file-200x300.png
_someImage.png
_myfile.jpg
_myfile-200x200.jpg
```

I'd like it to push _file-150x150.png, someImage.png and myfile.jpg into the array, and skip over the others.

```
$dir = 'wp-content/uploads/';
if(!is_dir($dir)){return;}
$url = get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/uploads/';

$imgs = array();
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) 
{
    $myfilter="";
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
        {
        if (!is_dir($file)&& $file != "." && $file != ".." && preg_match("/^[".$myfilter."_].*\.(bmp|jpeg|gif|png|jpg)$/i", $file)) 
            {
                array_push($imgs, $file);
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    } else {
        die('cannot open ' . $dir);
    }
    if($imgs) 
    {
        sort($imgs); 
        echo '<div>';
        foreach ($imgs as $idx=>$img) 
        {
            $class = ($idx == count($imgs) - 1 ? ' class="last"' : '');
            echo $prelink.' src="' . $url . $img . '" alt="' .$img . '"' . $class . ' />'.$postlink;
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem much of a pattern to me.

Comment: Yep, its not too obvious but the first pattern is matching filenames before the "-". The second pattern is what's after the "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 150x150 filename will always come after the base class, here's a regex you can use for that:

```
/^([^-.]+)(?:-150x150)?\.png\b(?!.*\1-150x150\.png\b)/ms
```

Explanation:

```
/
^                        #Match the start of the line
([^-.]+)                 #Match the first part of the file before the -sizeXsize
                         #And store it in the first capturing group.
(?:-150x150)?            #Match 0 or 1 of the desired size.
                         #(?:) is so that you don't store this match.
\.png\b                  #followed by .png
(?!.*\1-150x150\.png\b)  #A negative look ahead for the desired resolution.
                         #i.e. don't match the base if the desired resolution exists.
/ms                      #m is for multiline so that the ^ means start of line rather than start of string.
                         #s is for dotall so that the .* in the lookahead can match newlines.
```

The result will be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => _file-150x150.png
            [1] => _someImage.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => _file
            [1] => _someImage
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

1. Match *all* file names against `(.*?)(\-\d+x\d+)?(\.\w+)` and extract `$1` as the base name, `$2` as the optional resolution, and `$3` as the suffix;
2. Walk over the unique base names and check whether your desired resolution exists.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to do it is to add only base file names and files containing 150x150 in them to an associative array with the key as the base file name. Then, overwrite existing values with the files that contain 150x150 in the name.

```
    $files = array(
    '_file.png',
    '_file-150x150.png',
    '_file-200x300.png',
    '_someImage.png',
    '_myfile.jpg',
    '_myfile-200x200.jpg'   

    );

    $found = array();


    foreach ($files as $file ) {
        if (preg_match('/(_[^-]*)(-150x150)?\.(\w+)/', $file, $matches)) {
            $base = $matches[1];
            if (isset($found[$base]) && strstr($found[$base],'150x150')) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $found[$base] = $matches[0];
            }
        }

    }
```

Resulting `var_dump($found)`

```
array
  '_file' => string '_file-150x150.png' (length=17)
  '_someImage' => string '_someImage.png' (length=14)
  '_myfile' => string '_myfile.jpg' (length=11)
```

Sorry I didn't use your code. I figure you have enough experience to integrate yourself. If you need further explanation how to adapt to your needs, just let me know.